# Comparing Null to Null in merge statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, isnull, merge-statement

Which statement is perfect or better when dealing with billion of records for comparing NULL's in merge statement. I have tried with SET ANSI_NULLS OFF but that didn't work in merge statement. Here is my two ways

```
ISNULL(SRCColumn,-11111) = ISNULL(DSTColumn, -11111)
```

Or

```
SRCColumn = DSTColumn OR (SRCColumn  IS NULL AND DSTColumn  IS NULL)
```

Please let me know if there is any better way to deal with it. As I have around 15 columns to compare.

Comment: this link here is supposed to be the ISO way to do it, but its not supported: please vote for this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `SRCColumn = DSTColumn OR (SRCColumn  IS NULL AND DSTColumn  IS NULL)`

I'd suggest that you use this version because it most accurately expresses what you want SQL Server to do.

Both statements are logically equivalent (unless -11111 is a legal value for the column), however this statement is much more recognizable, and there's probably only a negligible difference in the run-time performance of the two statements.

Comment: I used the same statement. Though, thanks for posting the answer. I believe it would be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 2):

If you are more concerned with succinctness than performance, CHECKSUM() is also an option. It will match NULL -> NULL:

```
MERGE A
USING B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHEN MATCHED AND CHECKSUM(A.Col1, A.Col2, ... ) <> CHECKSUM(B.Col1, B.Col2, ... )
THEN UPDATE SET Col1 = B.Col1, Col1 = B.Col2, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the NOT comparison on matching:

```
MERGE [TGT]
USING [SRC]
ON [SRC].Key = [TGT]. Key
…

WHEN MATCHED AND
(
NOT ([TGT].[dw_patient_key] = [SRC].[dw_patient_key] OR ([TGT].[dw_patient_key] IS NULL AND [SRC].[dw_patient_key] IS NULL))
OR NOT ([TGT].[dw_patient_key] = [SRC].[dw_patient_key] OR ([TGT].[dw_patient_key] IS NULL AND [SRC].[dw_patient_key] IS NULL))
...
)
THEN UPDATE
...
```